# Why does the Euler method go bad when the time step $T$ is decreased?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

Consider below differential eqn $$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = y$$

In discrete form, with a time step $T$, using forward euler, it becomes
$$\dfrac{y[n+1]-y[n]}{T} = y[n]$$
Solving the difference eqn we get
$$y[n] = (1+T)^ny[0]$$

Intuitively if we decrease the time step $T$, the discrete form should approach more closely to the continuous form. But this doesn't seem to be the case as changing T moves the base of the $(1+T)^n$ away from $e$. Please look at the [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wc5zqakqw6) . Why did the euler method give this kind of solution which doesn't get better even if we decrease time step T ?

Answer (score 3):

The relation between discrete numerical approximations $y[n]$ and the solution $y(t)$ is given by $y(t=n \cdot T) \approx y[n]$.
In your plot you used the relation $y(t=n) \approx y[n]$.

If you plot $g\left(n\right)\ =\ \left(1+T\right)^{\frac{n}{T}}$ instead of 
$g\left(n\right)\ =\ \left(1+T\right)^{n}$, you will see convergence for small time steps $T$.

Comment: You mean $y(t = nT) \approx y[n]$.

Comment: Ahh yes t = nT gives n = t/T, but I see my error now... Ty :) Also if I may ask another perhaps silly question, if we let the initial value y[0] = 0, does this method fail ? Because the IVP problem can have dy/dt = y with y(0) = 0...

Comment: But if we let y[0] = 0 in the discrete form, we get all 0s hmm

Comment: @rsadhvika: What is the solution to the IVP problem with $y(0)=0$?

Comment: @Rahul  $$y(t) = Ce^t ; y(0) = 0 \implies  0 = Ce^0 \implies C = 0$$

Oh I see now the solution to IVP is also y = 0. It works just fine. Guess I should keep more faith in math in general haha.. Euler rocks! Thank you so much :)